# Deferred property for nullable enum

Tags: c#, enums, nullable

When I have an optional property in a class which can be null, I use the following pattern to defer it. I also use variations for value types such as integers.

```
    string myType;
    public string MyType
    {
        get { return myType ?? (myType = GetMyType()); }
    }
```

I'm trying to do the same with an enum - I would have expected the pattern to be something like this:

```
    MyEnum? myEnum;
    public MyEnum MyEnum
    {
        get { return myEnum ?? (myEnum = GetMyEnum()); }
    }
```

However, I'm getting an error stating that I can not explicitly make this conversion - anyone got an idea as to how I can get around it?

Comment: What does `GetMyEnum` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `(myEnum = GetMyEnum())` assignment is a `MyEnum?` because `myEnum` is `MyEnum?`; so you'll need to add a `.Value` or `.GetValueOrDefault()` after the `(...)`.

This works, for example:

```
public MyEnum MyEnum => myEnum ?? (myEnum = GetMyEnum()).GetValueOrDefault();
```

as does:

```
public MyEnum MyEnum => myEnum ?? (myEnum = GetMyEnum()) ?? 0;
```

or in C# 7.1:

```
public MyEnum MyEnum => myEnum ?? (myEnum = GetMyEnum()) ?? default;
```

Comment: @MatthewWatson yep; personally I'd favor the `GetValueOrDefault()` - avoids a branch - but `.Value` is easier to read

Comment: Oops sorry I deleted it when I saw your most recent edit, which was better. :)

Comment: Ah, I was way off the mark - been trying to add more ?? and ?: combos without any luck - thanks for the quick response.